# Set keyboard shortcut as double tap of modifier key on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I was wondering if i could set a keyboard shortcut on Mac as a double tap of a modifier key. For example, the default shortcut of start dictation command is a double tap of the Fn (Function) key. Can I set another command to have this shortcut?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't get an answer, you might try looking at some 'hot key' programs.  I know of AHK (Auto-Hot Key) language for PC, and it's pretty great, used to use it for several things.  Some suggested Mac alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332254/autohotkey-alternative-for-mac-os-x .  There's a way you can, in AHK, simulate a double press, and wouldn't be surprised if you could with those.  If you go this route, it'll take some minimal programming.

Comment: Please don't cross post to multiple Stack Exchange sites... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143155/set-keyboard-shortcut-as-double-tap-of-modifier-key-on-mac

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this with a utility called [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net/).  It allows you to define custom gestures with the touchpad.  I believe it has the ability to do modifier keys as well.

Comment: I can confirm that you CAN do it with BetterTouchTool.